# Delete files periodically in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, centos, cron

Is there any tool or service ( popular ) in Linux, which will help me clear the files from a given folder periodically (based on a pattern).

I don't want to write a cron-job or custom script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `Tmpwatch`, a tool to analyze and recursively delete files which have not been used certain period of time. If you do not want to run it periodically *by hand*, you should still create a crontab though.

See at http://thelinuxfaq.com/100-how-to-use-tmpwatch-command-in-linux